# How to detect color change of a TSemaphor control?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009, dll-injection, microsoft-ui-automation

I have an application A, which has a little text box, surrounded by a frame, which indicates whether the system is ready or not. The text and the frame reside inside a Delphi `TSemaphor` control.

1. During initialization, the frame is **yellow**.
2. When the initialization has completed and the system is ready, the frame turns **green**.

In another application B, I need to detect when application A has been initialized and is ready.

How can I do this (detect change of color of the frame) in application A with least possible effort and under following constraints

1. application A cannot be changed (I don't have its source code),
2. application A has no automation interface,
3. the only change that occurs, when the application A becomes ready, is the color change

?

There are following approaches to solving this problem I'm aware of:

1. Use image recognition (http://sikuli.org/)
2. Find out the color of the pixel at the respective position.
3. Use an injected DLL to get access to TSemaphore attributes.

Comment: You've given three answers to your question already. What more are you expecting? (By the way, `TSemaphor` is not a standard Delphi control; it was probably built by the developers of the application you're trying to observe.)

Comment: I expect a more ELEGANT solution, since each of the proposed methods has serious drawbacks. Methods 1 and 2 rely on the control always being at the same place (if the vendor of the application A releases a new version, where the control is located at another place, I'll need to update application B). Method 3 is complicated by its very nature and I try to avoid it.

Comment: There isn't going to be a more elegant solution.